# Check difference in data between 2 tables on database

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby

I am trying to check the difference of data in 2 tables between 2 different database on 2 different servers.

I would compare them by `primary_key(id)` but how would I properly do this? The tables engine are `InnoDB` not `Federated`.

My initial approach is something something like: (*untested code*)

```
v2 = v2db.query("SELECT id FROM #{table1}")
v3 = v3db.query("SELECT id FROM #{table2}")

diff = v2 - v3

if diff.count > 0
  puts "diff is greater than 0"
elsif diff.count < 0
  puts "diff is less than 0"
else
  puts "tables in sync"
```

Any idea on a better approach as the table contains `30,000+` rows and loading this all into a result would be troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see the difference only on number of row I guess the solution would be something like this:

```
v2 = v2db.query("SELECT count(id) FROM #{table1}")
v3 = v3db.query("SELECT count(id) FROM #{table2}")

diff = v2 - v3

if diff.count > 0
  puts "diff is greater than 0"
elsif diff.count < 0
  puts "diff is less than 0"
else
  puts "tables in sync"
```

however you have to create an arraylist with id for each query and to check the 2 arraylists on ids, if you want to check if they are identical.

- check the size of the first arraylist
- check the size of the second
- if are not equal return false
- if the size of both arraylists is equal then
- iterate with the size of the common length if there is a difference
  are not equal return false
- if there is no difference for all rows then return true

Complexity for this algorithm is O(n).

Comment: no I don't want to count the rows, both database might have the same number of rows but not the same content. I need to see the difference in content.

Comment: if you want to check the difference then the algorithm is Ok, so in step 5 you can check about content is the same or not... for each column, the difference is that you have to fetch all data. another approach is to make a hash for each row taking in consideration the data. At the end you check only the hash not all columns data. What do you think? Something like checksum :)